# Worksheets.Cells.NumberFormat doing the opposite

Tags: vb.net, excel

i'm facing a problem that i really cant understand at all. When creating a excel file i have multi column and on each column i want to format its cells. So far so good, almost all of them are working but when i try to format the Date column it doesn't work at all. The cell format is ignoring completely the formation i'm passing on `.NumberFormat`. This is the code i'm using for formatting:

```
 'Set textAlignment on Double
            For c As Integer = 1 To dt.Columns.Count
                If dt.Columns(c - 1).ColumnName = "Kasnr" Or dt.Columns(c - 1).ColumnName = "Nr" Then
                    For r As Integer = 1 To dt.Rows.Count
                        wBook.Worksheets(1).Cells(r, c).HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter
                    Next
                ElseIf dt.Columns(c - 1).ColumnName = "BeginSaldo" Or dt.Columns(c - 1).ColumnName = "EindSaldo" Or dt.Columns(c - 1).ColumnName = "bedragExBTW" Or dt.Columns(c - 1).ColumnName = "Transactiedatum" Or dt.Columns(c - 1).ColumnName = "Grootboeknummer" Then
                    For r As Integer = 1 To dt.Rows.Count
                        wBook.Worksheets(1).Cells(r, c).HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight
                    Next
                ElseIf dt.Columns(c - 1).ColumnName = "Datum" Then
                    For r As Integer = 1 To dt.Rows.Count
                        wBook.Worksheets(1).Cells(r, c).NumberFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy;@"
                    Next
                Else
                        Continue For
                End If
            Next
```

Now on `wBook.Worksheets(1).Cells(r, c).NumberFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy;@"` it displays as '11-18-2013' and i really want a european dateformat as '18-11-2013'. Now if i do `wBook.Worksheets(1).Cells(r, c).NumberFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy;@"` then the excel column will display '18-11-2013'.. Thats weird because im setting it to the other way around.. Does anyone encounter something like this before?

EDIT:
code where i set the value to each cell:

```
Dim dr1 As System.Data.DataRow
            For i As Integer = 0 To datagridView1.RowCount - 1
                dr1 = dset.Tables(0).NewRow
                For j As Integer = 0 To datagridView1.Columns.Count - 1
                    If TypeOf (datagridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value) Is DateTime Then
                        'Format Date to display on Excel file
                        If datagridView1.Columns(j).Name = "Datum" Or datagridView1.Columns(j).Name = "Transactiedatum" Then
                            Dim datumFormat As String = datagridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.Date.Day & "/" & datagridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.Date.Month & "/" & datagridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.Date.Year

                            dr1(j) = datumFormat
                        ElseIf datagridView1.Columns(j).Name = "Periode" Then
                            Dim PeriodeFormat As String = datagridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.Date.Year & "/" & datagridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.Date.Month

                            dr1(j) = PeriodeFormat
                        Else
                            dr1(j) = datagridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value
                        End If
                    ElseIf TypeOf (datagridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value) Is Double Or TypeOf (datagridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value) Is Integer Then
                        'Format Double/force 2 decimals
                        If datagridView1.Columns(j).Name = "BeginSaldo" Or datagridView1.Columns(j).Name = "EindSaldo" Or datagridView1.Columns(j).Name = "bedragExBTW" Then

                            dr1(j) = DMDbl(datagridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value).ToString("N2")
                        Else

                            dr1(j) = datagridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value
                        End If
                    Else

                        dr1(j) = datagridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value
                    End If
                Next
                dset.Tables(0).Rows.Add(dr1)
            Next
```

As you can see um passing a string on both(Datum and TransactieDatum). But Datum column is always getting a format(incorrect one) and Transactiedatum, is also a date, is not getting any format at all.

EDIT2:
code where i set the cell values on excel:

```
For Each dc In dt.Columns
                colIndex = colIndex + 1
                excel.Cells(1, colIndex) = dc.ColumnName
            Next

            For Each dr In dt.Rows
                rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
                colIndex = 0
                For Each dc In dt.Columns
                    colIndex = colIndex + 1
                    excel.Cells(rowIndex + 1, colIndex) = dr(dc.ColumnName)
                Next
            Next
```

Comment: Which component are you using? Or is this VBA?

Comment: @Teejay he is using VB.NET, Interop (tip: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter)

Comment: There might be some problems while dealing with Excel and Dates (and intending to use a format different than the one in the culture of the given computer); usually you can avoid any of these issues by writing strings (instead of date variables) to the cell. Can you please include the code you are using to write the given date values to the these cells (you have posted just the cell-formatting bits)?

Comment: Yes im using VB.NET with the interop component. @varocarbas, im passing a string to the cell and not a date, thats also something weird i have notice. I will update my post with the code where i set the cell value.

Comment: Thanks for adding the code; although it still does not include the part where you write to the Excel cell; something on the lines of: wBook.Worksheets(1).Cells(r, c).Value = DateAsString. In any case if you are saying that this step is done (you are writing text values to the cells), I am not sure what might be the problem: it should work fine in this case.

Comment: Didn't know you can operate directly on Excel spreadsheets, without a component (I currently use SpreadSheetGear)

Comment: @varocarbas Post updated, and yes im passing it as string so it really should work correctly.. Really weird.. maybe somehting with the column?

Comment: Your code does not follow exactly the format I have proposed. Could you please perform the corresponding adaptation and confirm that it does not work either, that is: excel.Cells(rowIndex + 1, colIndex).Value = dr(dc.ColumnName).ToString Also better write the .NumberFormat right after the population to be completely sure that you are changing the format of that cell.

Comment: Hi @varocarbas i did change the code as you asked, and also provide the format directly when populate the cells but i still got the same problem, the 'Datum' column is coming out as '11-1-2013'.. this weird thing is frustrating and at the same time funny. ahah oh well..

Comment: Sorry but cannot be of help as far as cannot reproduce your conditions. If I start a new VB.NET app connected by Interop to Excel, I am able to change the date format in a cell without any problem by doing what I am saying. Once the only part dealing with dates is Excel (and the .NET variable is a string) there shouldn't be absolutely any problem. No idea what might be wrong in your case. In your situation, I would start a new project, confirm that the behaviour is the one I am saying and keep copying from your old project until finding out the bit giving problems (no idea what might be).